# Empty Xcode 4 cache

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Is there a way to empty the Xcode 4 cache?

Comment: Duplicate Question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to the organizer then Projects, click on the project you want to clean. Finally  click on the delete on the right.

Answer (score 0):

By Xcode cache, do you mean the build directories?  If so, select "Clean" from the "Product" menu.

Comment: No. I want a similar feature to the "Empty Caches" in the Xcode 3 menu.

Answer (score 0):

For XCode 4:

1. Click Command+Shift+K.
2. Or go to Product -> Clean in the menu.
3. Or click Command+Option+Shift+K to clean the build folder.

On the simulator, click the "Reset content and settings" in the simulator menu.